# How to avoid the XML parser go to the nested tag, or only allow the outer tag only in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

Here is a simple XML:

```
<MSG>
    <ID>123<ID>
    <Node>
       <ID>456<ID>
    </Node>
</MSG>
```

And I got a parser which is subclass of `ParentParser` and implements `NSXMLParserDelegate`

The `ParentParser` is something like this:

```
- (id)initWithXmlString:(NSString *)xmlString
{
    if ( (self = [super init]) ) {
        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:xmlString];
        self.xml = str;
        [str release];

        self.storingData     = NO;
        self.receiveString   = [NSMutableString string];
        self.elementsToParse = [NSArray array];
    }

    return self;
}
```

And this is how I parse the XML:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

   if (self.m_oMyObject) {
      if (self.storingData) {
         NSString *tempStr = [self.receiveString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                              [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
         [self.receiveString setString:@""];

         if ([elementName isEqualToString:kID]) {
             //Go in twice
         }
     //============ Code skips ===================
```

As you can see, the `kID`, String `ID` had been parse twice. But I would like to have the `123` only, not the `456`, which is inside the `<Node>` tag, how can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can make `NSXMLParser` skip nested elements, but you could keep track of the current level by incrementing an instance variable `level` in `parser:didStartElement:...` and decrementing it in `parser:didEndElement:...`.